# React: issue with the search and filter function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-binding, bind

I'm working on a component that should be able to:

1. Search by input - Using the input field a function will be called after the onBlur event got triggered. After the **onBlur** event the **startSearch**() method will run.
2. Filter by a selected genre - From an other component the user can select a genre from a list  with genres. After the **onClick** event the **startFilter**() method will run.

**GOOD NEWS:**
I got the 2 functions above working.

**BAD NEWS:**
The above 2 functions don't work correct. Please see the code underneath. The 2 calls underneath work, but only if I comment one of the 2 out.  I tried to tweak the **startSearch**() method in various ways, but I just keep walking to a big fat wall.

```
//////Searching works
//////this.filter(this.state.searchInput);

//Filtering works           
this.startFilter(this.state.searchInput);
```

**QUESTION**
**How can I get the filter/search method working?**. Unfortunately simply putting them in an if/else is not the solution (see comments in the code).

```js
import { Component } from 'preact';
import listData from '../../assets/data.json';
import { Link } from 'preact-router/match';
import style from './style';

export default class List extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedStreamUrl: '',
    searchInput: '',
    showDeleteButton: false,
    searchByGenre: false,
    list: []
  };

  startFilter(input, filterByGenre) {
    this.setState({
      searchByGenre: true,
      searchInput: input,
      showDeleteButton: true
    });
    alert('startFilter  ');
    console.log(this.state.searchByGenre);
    /////////---------------------------------
    document.getElementById('searchField').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('searchField').value = input;
    document.getElementById('searchField').focus();
    // document.getElementById('searchField').blur()
    document.getElementById('searchField').disabled = true;

    console.log(input);
    this.filter(input);
  }

  //search
  startSearch(input) {
    alert('startSearch  ');
    console.log(this.state.searchByGenre);

    //komt uit render()
    if (!this.state.searchByGenre) {
      //check for input

      this.setState({
        searchInput: input.target.value,
        showDeleteButton: true
      });

      //Searching works
      //this.filter(this.state.searchInput);

      //Filtering works
      this.startFilter(this.state.searchInput);

      // DOESNT WORK:
      // if (this.state.searchInput != "") {
      //  this.filter(this.state.searchInput);
      // } else {
      //  this.startFilter(this.state.searchInput);
      // }
    }
  }

  setAllLists(allLists) {
    console.log('setAllLists');
    console.log(this.state.searchByGenre);
    this.setState({ list: allLists });
    //document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  filter(input) {
    let corresondingGenre = [];
    let filteredLists = listData.filter(item1 => {
      var test;
      if (this.state.searchByGenre) {
        alert('--this.state.searchByGenre');
        //filterByGenre
        //& item1.properties.genre == input

        for (var i = 0; i < item1.properties.genre.length; i++) {
          if (item1.properties.genre[i].includes(input)) {
            corresondingGenre.push(item1);
            test = item1.properties.genre[i].indexOf(input) !== -1;

            return test;
          }
          this.setState({ list: corresondingGenre });
        }
      } else {
        //searchByTitle
        alert('--default');
        test = item1.title.indexOf(input.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) !== -1;
      }
      return test;
    });
    console.log('filterdLists:');
    console.log(filteredLists);
    console.log('corresondingGenre:');
    console.log(corresondingGenre);
    //alert(JSON.stringify(filteredLists))
    this.setState({ list: filteredLists });
  }

  removeInput() {
    console.log('removeInput    ');
    console.log(this.state.searchByGenre);
    this.setState({
      searchInput: '',
      showDeleteButton: false,
      searchByGenre: false
    });
    document.getElementById('searchField').disabled = false;
    this.filter(this.state.searchInput);
  }

  render() {
    //alle 's komen in deze array, zodat ze gefilterd kunnen worden OBV title.
    if (
      this.state.list === undefined ||
      (this.state.list.length == 0 && this.state.searchInput == '')
    ) {
      //init list
      console.log('render ');
      console.log(this.state.searchByGenre);
      this.filter(this.state.searchInput);
    }

    return (
      <div class={style.list_container}>
        <input
          class={style.searchBar}
          type="text"
          id="searchField"
          placeholder={this.state.searchInput}
          onBlur={this.startSearch.bind(this)}
        />

        {this.state.searchByGenre ? <h1>ja</h1> : <h1>nee</h1>}
        {this.state.showDeleteButton ? (
          <button class={style.deleteButton} onClick={() => this.removeInput()}>
            Remove
          </button>
        ) : null}
        {this.state.list.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <p>{item.title}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried making startSearch() an ES6 arrow function? you wouldn't need the bind(this)

Comment: Let me see if I get it right, you need the value from `this.state.searchByGenre` when you call the function `startSearch` at the end of the function, but it changes on the way, that's it?

Comment: provide complete class code

Comment: @Foo it looks like the problem isn't about passing the value to the function, but the state changing on the change. I will update my answer to cover it, but maybe you should edit the question too.

Comment: @Toug I've changed the Title and Question and I've added more code. I will check at your links, thanks!

Comment: what's in `ListData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you are asking is not clear. But try to be explicit with your component to help debug the issue. For example, use a constructor and declare your component state in there. Also do your .bind for the event in there to be concise.

The following example captures the state variable to be true when the onBlur event is fired, which is the same as its initial state value:

```
class List extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        searchByGenre: true
    };

    this.startSearch = this.startSearch.bind(this);
}

startSearch() {
    // This value is true
    console.log(this.state.searchByGenre)
}

render() {
    return (
        <input 
            type="text" 
            id="searchField" 
            placeholder="Search" 
            value={this.state.searchInput} 
            onBlur={this.startSearch} 
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've just updated my code. Hopefully it clears my question.

Answer (score 2):

To make your search and filter work properly you need two arrays.

```
state = {
  selectedStreamUrl: "",
  searchInput: "",
  showDeleteButton: false,
  // searchByGenre: false, // removed, will use filter by from a list
  // by default both arrays have the same value
  list: listData, // holds the original data, doesn't change
  filteredList: listData, // holds filterd list, filtered when the user types in input
  // by default filter by title, will change when user, use a value from a list
  filterBy: 'title', 
}
```

Your search function will use `this.state.filterBy` value, to filter the array. No need to create multiple functions. This gives you flexibility as you can filter using multiple values from a dropdown and you don't have to change the code.

```
startSearch = (value) => {

  const search = value.toLowerCase();
  // get filter value title, genre, etc
  const searchKey = this.state.filterBy;

  this.setState({
    searchInput: value,
    filteredList: this.state.list.filter(item => {
      // filter base on key item['title'] or item['genre'] etc
      return item && item[searchKey].toLowerCase().includes(search)
    }),
    showDeleteButton: !!value,
  })

}
```

Remove input function

```
removeInput = () => {
  this.setState({
    filterBy: 'title',
    showDeleteButton: false,
    searchInput: '',
  }, () => this.startSearch(this.state.searchInput));
}
```

I see you are doing a lot of `document.getElementById("searchField").disabled = false;`. Don't manipulate the dom directly, let react manages this for you.

**SEE DEMO BELOW**

```css
h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.image-container {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.info-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 10px
}

.title {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.cover {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

const style = {};
const listData = [
    {
      "vote_count": 806,
      "id": 420817,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.2,
      "title": "Aladdin",
      "popularity": 476.676,
      "poster_path": "/3iYQTLGoy7QnjcUYRJy4YrAgGvp.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Aladdin",
      "genre": "Adventure",
      "backdrop_path": "/v4yVTbbl8dE1UP2dWu5CLyaXOku.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "A kindhearted street urchin named Aladdin embarks on a magical adventure after finding a lamp that releases a wisecracking genie while a power-hungry Grand Vizier vies for the same lamp that has the power to make their deepest wishes come true.",
      "release_date": "2019-05-22"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 70,
      "id": 373571,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.4,
      "title": "Godzilla: King of the Monsters",
      "popularity": 143.161,
      "poster_path": "/pU3bnutJU91u3b4IeRPQTOP8jhV.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Godzilla: King of the Monsters",
      "genre": "Action",
      "backdrop_path": "/mzRJpkWPjXdXak0WCc8ZxVH4hug.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "The new story follows the heroic efforts of the crypto-zoological agency Monarch as its members face off against a battery of god-sized monsters, including the mighty Godzilla, who collides with Mothra, Rodan, and his ultimate nemesis, the three-headed King Ghidorah. When these ancient super-species—thought to be mere myths—rise again, they all vie for supremacy, leaving humanity’s very existence hanging in the balance.",
      "release_date": "2019-05-29"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 984,
      "id": 447404,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7,
      "title": "Pokémon Detective Pikachu",
      "popularity": 109.979,
      "poster_path": "/wgQ7APnFpf1TuviKHXeEe3KnsTV.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Pokémon Detective Pikachu",
      "genre": "Mystery",
      "backdrop_path": "/nDP33LmQwNsnPv29GQazz59HjJI.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "In a world where people collect pocket-size monsters (Pokémon) to do battle, a boy comes across an intelligent monster who seeks to be a detective.",
      "release_date": "2019-05-03"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 136,
      "id": 531309,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 5.6,
      "title": "Brightburn",
      "popularity": 108.875,
      "poster_path": "/sJWwkYc9ajwnPRSkqj8Aue5JbKz.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Brightburn",
      "genre": "Horror",
      "backdrop_path": "/uHEI6v8ApQusjbaRZ8o7WcLYeWb.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "What if a child from another world crash-landed on Earth, but instead of becoming a hero to mankind, he proved to be something far more sinister?",
      "release_date": "2019-05-09"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 570,
      "id": 527641,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 8.1,
      "title": "Five Feet Apart",
      "popularity": 72.32,
      "poster_path": "/kreTuJBkUjVWePRfhHZuYfhNE1T.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Five Feet Apart",
      "genre": "Romance",
      "backdrop_path": "/27ZkYMWynuK2qiDP6awc3MsCaOs.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Seventeen-year-old Stella spends most of her time in the hospital as a cystic fibrosis patient. Her life is full of routines, boundaries and self-control -- all of which get put to the test when she meets Will, an impossibly charming teen who has the same illness. There's an instant flirtation, though restrictions dictate that they must maintain a safe distance between them. As their connection intensifies, so does the temptation to throw the rules out the window and embrace that attraction.",
      "release_date": "2019-03-15"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 162,
      "id": 449562,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.1,
      "title": "The Hustle",
      "popularity": 71.346,
      "poster_path": "/qibqW5Dnvqp4hcEnoTARbQgxwJy.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "The Hustle",
      "genre": "Comedy",
      "backdrop_path": "/s6awXOxTKYQLSktiIJfI3969dZH.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Two female scam artists, one low rent and the other high class, compete to swindle a naïve tech prodigy out of his fortune. A remake of the 1988 comedy \"Dirty Rotten Scoundrels.\"",
      "release_date": "2019-05-09"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 88,
      "id": 504608,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.7,
      "title": "Rocketman",
      "popularity": 66.812,
      "poster_path": "/f4FF18ia7yTvHf2izNrHqBmgH8U.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Rocketman",
      "genre": "Drama",
      "backdrop_path": "/oAr5bgf49vxga9etWoQpAeRMvhp.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "The story of Elton John's life, from his years as a prodigy at the Royal Academy of Music through his influential and enduring musical partnership with Bernie Taupin.",
      "release_date": "2019-05-22"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 124,
      "id": 505600,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7,
      "title": "Booksmart",
      "popularity": 57.801,
      "poster_path": "/Awyg5IdELQV3sBoErhJ9QVcX8TA.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Booksmart",
      "genre": "Drama, Comedy",
      "backdrop_path": "/wcAqndL2MkIjPrCrYeuE794weNE.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Two academic teenage superstars realize, on the eve of their high school graduation, that they should have worked less and played more. Determined to never fall short of their peers, the girls set out on a mission to cram four years of fun into one night.",
      "release_date": "2019-05-24"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 10,
      "id": 502416,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 4.8,
      "title": "Ma",
      "popularity": 55.328,
      "poster_path": "/6n7ASmQ1wY2cxTubFFGlcvPpyk7.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Ma",
      "genre": "Comedy, Horror",
      "backdrop_path": "/mBOv5YrX5QGr5CusK0PKSHuxOt9.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Sue Ann is a loner who keeps to herself in her quiet Ohio town. One day, she is asked by Maggie, a new teenager in town, to buy some booze for her and her friends, and Sue Ann sees the chance to make some unsuspecting, if younger, friends of her own.  She offers the kids the chance to avoid drinking and driving by hanging out in the basement of her home. But there are some house rules: One of the kids has to stay sober. Don’t curse. Never go upstairs. And call her “Ma.”  But as Ma’s hospitality starts to curdle into obsession, what began as a teenage dream turns into a terrorizing nightmare, and Ma’s place goes from the best place in town to the worst place on earth.",
      "release_date": "2019-05-29"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 88,
      "id": 535581,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 5.9,
      "title": "The Dead Don't Die",
      "popularity": 52.857,
      "poster_path": "/ycMSfP8KRFsVUWfbSxSFpD97QfD.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "The Dead Don't Die",
      "genre": "Comedy, Horror",
      "backdrop_path": "/cXyfAViYly0Lk2CVpEKgYbt9wKQ.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "In a small peaceful town, zombies suddenly rise to terrorize the town. Now three bespectacled police officers and a strange Scottish morgue expert must band together to defeat the undead.",
      "release_date": "2019-05-15"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 0,
      "id": 320288,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 0,
      "title": "Dark Phoenix",
      "popularity": 52.433,
      "poster_path": "/kZv92eTc0Gg3mKxqjjDAM73z9cy.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Dark Phoenix",
      "genre": "Action, Science Fiction",
      "backdrop_path": "/A2oPzeKjSpCovYLqoDDXFbrJgyS.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "The X-Men face their most formidable and powerful foe when one of their own, Jean Grey, starts to spiral out of control. During a rescue mission in outer space, Jean is nearly killed when she's hit by a mysterious cosmic force. Once she returns home, this force not only makes her infinitely more powerful, but far more unstable. The X-Men must now band together to save her soul and battle aliens that want to use Grey's new abilities to rule the galaxy.",
      "release_date": "2019-06-05"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 10,
      "id": 496243,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 9.4,
      "title": "Parasite",
      "popularity": 46.835,
      "poster_path": "/7IiTTgloJzvGI1TAYymCfbfl3vT.jpg",
      "original_language": "ko",
      "original_title": "기생충",
      "genre": "Drama, Comedy",
      "backdrop_path": "/ny5aCtglk2kceGAuAdiyqbhBBAf.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "All unemployed, Ki-taek's family takes peculiar interest in the wealthy and glamorous Parks for their livelihood until they get entangled in an unexpected incident.",
      "release_date": "2019-05-30"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 71,
      "id": 526050,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.2,
      "title": "Little",
      "popularity": 43.334,
      "poster_path": "/4MDB6jJl3U7xK1Gw64zIqt9pQA4.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Little",
      "genre": "Comedy, Fantasy",
      "backdrop_path": "/tmM78qRhpg0i2Cky8Q8hXKASOXY.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "A woman receives the chance to relive the life of her younger self, at a point in her life when the pressures of adulthood become too much for her to bear.",
      "release_date": "2019-04-04"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 1181,
      "id": 329996,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.6,
      "title": "Dumbo",
      "popularity": 39.349,
      "poster_path": "/279PwJAcelI4VuBtdzrZASqDPQr.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Dumbo",
      "genre": "Adventure, Animation, Fantasy",
      "backdrop_path": "/5tFt6iuGnKapHl5tw0X0cKcnuVo.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "A young elephant, whose oversized ears enable him to fly, helps save a struggling circus, but when the circus plans a new venture, Dumbo and his friends discover dark secrets beneath its shiny veneer.",
      "release_date": "2019-03-27"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 19,
      "id": 412117,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.5,
      "title": "The Secret Life of Pets 2",
      "popularity": 38.485,
      "poster_path": "/q3mKnSkzp1doIsCye6ap4KIUAbu.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "The Secret Life of Pets 2",
      "genre": "Comedy, Animation, Adventure",
      "backdrop_path": "/5mFcjZ58f9Pqg5RNv493XlfgzIX.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "The further adventures of Max the dog and his furry animal friends.",
      "release_date": "2019-05-24"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 104,
      "id": 471506,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.1,
      "title": "Greta",
      "popularity": 34.139,
      "poster_path": "/9hBpFyJ3pGdupXbaC2L7nGvLMBn.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Greta",
      "genre": "Thriller, Drama, Mystery",
      "backdrop_path": "/n67gpLtNFXqpGkM2ZdQoPLjTnI.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "A young woman returns an elderly widow’s lost purse, leading to an unlikely relationship between the two — until the young woman discovers her elder might not be all that she seems.",
      "release_date": "2019-02-28"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 0,
      "id": 455957,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 0,
      "title": "Domino",
      "popularity": 31.812,
      "poster_path": "/rrX1ojdd068aHlrGq5Khd92a3ba.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Domino",
      "genre": "Crime, Thriller",
      "backdrop_path": "/1NGFwLyUo6YYLYD6jUaiWXgxh6n.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Seeking justice for his partner’s murder by an ISIS member, a Copenhagen police officer finds himself caught in a cat and mouse game with a duplicitous CIA agent who is using the killer as a pawn to trap other ISIS members.",
      "release_date": "2019-05-31"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 45,
      "id": 514439,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.5,
      "title": "Breakthrough",
      "popularity": 29.475,
      "poster_path": "/t58dx7JIgchr9If5uxn3NmHaHoS.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Breakthrough",
      "genre": "Drama",
      "backdrop_path": "/6jaNHf9ja84YG3KWMDK1nOnvGDg.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "When he was 14, Smith drowned in Lake St. Louis and was dead for nearly an hour. According to reports at the time, CPR was performed 27 minutes to no avail. Then the youth's mother, Joyce Smith, entered the room, praying loudly. Suddenly, there was a pulse, and Smith came around.",
      "release_date": "2019-04-11"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 98,
      "id": 459992,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.8,
      "title": "Long Shot",
      "popularity": 28.19,
      "poster_path": "/m2ttWZ8rMRwIMT7zA48Jo6mTkDS.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Long Shot",
      "genre": "Comedy, Romance",
      "backdrop_path": "/88r25ghJzVYKq0vaOApqEOZsQlD.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "When Fred Flarsky reunites with his first crush, one of the most influential women in the world, Charlotte Field, he charms her. As she prepares to make a run for the Presidency, Charlotte hires Fred as her speechwriter and sparks fly.",
      "release_date": "2019-05-02"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 145,
      "id": 376865,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 5.8,
      "title": "High Life",
      "popularity": 27.909,
      "poster_path": "/wElOvH7H6sLElsTOLu1MY6oWRUx.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "High Life",
      "genre": "Science Fiction, Drama, Mystery, Thriller",
      "backdrop_path": "/6gHdAO1Lvk9bjzhY4hX3wVRkAhF.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Monte and his baby daughter are the last survivors of a damned and dangerous mission to the outer reaches of the solar system. They must now rely on each other to survive as they hurtle toward the oblivion of a black hole.",
      "release_date": "2018-11-07"
    }
  ]

class SearchItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="image-container">
          <img className="cover" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.props.image}`} />
        </div>
        <div className="info-container">
          <p className="title">{this.props.title}</p>
          <p>Genre: {this.props.genre}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}



class List extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedStreamUrl: "",
    searchInput: "",
    showDeleteButton: false,
    searchByGenre: false,
    list: listData,
    filteredList: listData,
    filterBy: 'title',
  }

  //search
  startSearch = (value) => {

    const search = value.toLowerCase();
    const searchKey = this.state.filterBy;

    this.setState({
      searchInput: value,
      filteredList: this.state.list.filter(item => {
        return item && item[searchKey].toLowerCase().includes(search)
      }),
      showDeleteButton: value ? true : false,
    })

  }

  setAllLists = (allLists) => {
    console.log("setAllLists")
    console.log(this.state.searchByGenre)
    this.setState({ filteredList: allLists })
    //document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";  
  }

  removeInput = () => {
    this.setState({
      filterBy: 'title',
      showDeleteButton: false,
      searchInput: '',
    }, () => this.startSearch(this.state.searchInput));
  }

  filterBy = (event) => {
    const filter =  event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      filterBy: filter
    });
    
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div class={style.list_container}>
        <div>
          <input value={this.state.searchInput} class={style.searchBar} type="text" id="searchField" placeholder={this.state.searchInput} onChange={(e) => this.startSearch(e.target.value)} ></input>
          <select onChange={this.filterBy}>
            <option selected={this.state.filterBy === 'title'} value="title">Title</option>
            <option selected={this.state.filterBy === 'genre'} value="genre">Genre</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        {
          this.state.filterBy === 'genre' ?
            <h1>ja</h1>
            :
            <h1>nee</h1>
        }
        {
          this.state.showDeleteButton ?
            <button class={style.deleteButton} onClick={() => this.removeInput()}>Remove</button>
            : null
        }
        {
          this.state.filteredList.map((item, index) => {
            return <SearchItem image={item.poster_path} title={item.title} genre={item.genre} />
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Comment: let me know if it doesn't work or if I need to change something.

Comment: hey thanks for the effort, but in didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: After I call this.setState({ List: newArray}) the rerender won't get triggered. Do you have any idea why this is? If I use oldArray.splice() it does trigger the rerender, but splice only removes one item. If you can help me with this I'll give you the 50 my friend!

Comment: @Foo like I said in my code don't change `List`, as it holds the original data, use `filteredList`. Leave `List` in state don't set it.

Comment: @Foo so where are you doing that, I don't see it in your code? share your code here https://codeshare.io/an7Erv

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction. I couldn't use your code, because I use Preact. But I've solved by not changing the initial array AND!!! moving the genreList with hrefs into the same class as the List (code above). Because after a genre href got clicked the class with the List did receive the trigger, but the state got reset afterwards. So by moving the genreList into the same class as the List the state didn't get reset.

Comment: BTW: if you know a solution for the "reset state" issue described in my previous comment please let me know. But for now I'm happy with a working search and filter ;).

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go:

change the bind to the constructor (and the state too!)

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { searchByGenre: true }

        this.startSeach = startSearch.bind(this);
    }

    startSearch(searchByGenre) {
        //This is false after the call 
        console.log(this.state.searchByGenre)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input class={style.searchBar} type="text" id="searchField" placeholder="Search" value={this.state.searchInput} onBlur={this.startSearch} >
            </input>
        )
    }
```

That way you can use the `startSearch` with arguments:

```
<input class={style.searchBar} 
  type="text" 
  id="searchField" 
  placeholder="Search" 
  value={this.state.searchInput} 
  onBlur={() => this.startSearch(this.state.searchByGenre)} 
>
```

**OR** you can change the `startSearch` to be an arrow function, and remove the bind from the constructor:

```
startSearch = (searchByGenre) => {
  //This is false after the call 
  console.log(this.state.searchByGenre)
}
```

You can take a look at why this happens [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html).

**Edit**: The link talks about typeScript, but ignore it and focus on the *arrow function/bind* part

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. I've just updated my code. Hopefully it clears my question.

Comment: @Foo take a look at your `startSearch` function, you have unreachable code. the second `if (!this.state.searchByGenre)` will always be true, since it's inside another `if (!this.state.searchByGenre)` and there's nothing between them that can change it.

Comment: Good point thanks! Please see my comment in the code in the startSearch().  I've debugged and found out that after the:  'document.getElementById("searchField")' in the startFilter() everything is being reset even with the phat arrow method.

Comment: You should always avoid manipulating the DOM (html elements) directly when using React. For example, when you do `document.getElementById('searchField').value = input` you change the input value, but the input value is bonded to `this.state.searchInput`, and this can cause you some problems. I will update your code and add it to my answer so we can get back to your problem.

Comment: thanks. Did you already updated my code? I will start a bounty in 12h.