# React search and filter methods issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

I'm working on a component that should be able to:

1. Search by input - Using the input field a function will be called after the onBlur event got triggered. After the **onBlur** event the **startSearch**() method will run.
2. Filter by a selected genre - From an other component the user can select a genre from a list  with genres. After the **onClick** event the **startFilter**() method will run.

**GOOD NEWS:**
I got the 2 functions above working.

**BAD NEWS:**
The above 2 functions don't work correct. Please see the code underneath. The 2 calls underneath work, but only if I comment one of the 2 out.  I tried to tweak the **startSearch**() method in various ways, but I just keep walking to a big fat wall.

> ```
>         //////Searching works
>         //////this.filter(this.state.searchInput);
>
>          //Filtering works            
>          this.startFilter(this.state.searchInput);
> ```

**QUESTION**
**How can I get the filter/search method working?**. Unfortunately simply putting them in an if/else is not the solution (see comments in the code).

```js
import { Component } from 'preact';
import listData from '../../assets/data.json';
import { Link } from 'preact-router/match';
import style from './style';



export default class List extends Component {
 state = {
  selectedStreamUrl: "",
  searchInput: "",
  showDeleteButton: false,
  searchByGenre: false,
  list: [],

 }


 startFilter(input, filterByGenre) {
  this.setState({
   searchByGenre: true,
   searchInput: input,
   showDeleteButton: true
  });
  alert("startFilter  ")
  console.log(this.state.searchByGenre)
  /////////---------------------------------
  document.getElementById("searchField").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('searchField').value = input
  document.getElementById('searchField').focus()
  // document.getElementById('searchField').blur()
  document.getElementById("searchField").disabled = true;


  console.log(input)
  this.filter(input);


 }

 //search
 startSearch(input) {
  alert("startSearch  ")
  console.log(this.state.searchByGenre)

  //komt uit render()
  if (!this.state.searchByGenre) {
   //check for input

   this.setState({
    searchInput: input.target.value,
    showDeleteButton: true,
   })

   //Searching works
   //this.filter(this.state.searchInput);

   //Filtering works
   this.startFilter(this.state.searchInput);

   // DOESNT WORK:
   // if (this.state.searchInput != "") {
   //  this.filter(this.state.searchInput);
   // } else {
   //  this.startFilter(this.state.searchInput);
   // }
  }


 }

 setAllLists(allLists) {
  console.log("setAllLists")
  console.log(this.state.searchByGenre)
  this.setState({ list: allLists })
  //document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";  
 }

 filter(input) {
  let corresondingGenre = [];
  let filteredLists = listData.filter(

   (item1) => {
    var test;
    if (this.state.searchByGenre) {
     alert("--this.state.searchByGenre")
     //filterByGenre
     //& item1.properties.genre == input

     for (var i = 0; i < item1.properties.genre.length; i++) {
      if (item1.properties.genre[i].includes(input)) {
       corresondingGenre.push(item1);
       test = item1.properties.genre[i].indexOf(input) !== -1;

       return test;
      }
      this.setState({ list: corresondingGenre })
     }

    } else {
     //searchByTitle
     alert("--default")
     test = item1.title.indexOf(input.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) !== -1;
    }
    return test;
   })
  console.log("filterdLists:")
  console.log(filteredLists)
  console.log("corresondingGenre:")
  console.log(corresondingGenre)
  //alert(JSON.stringify(filteredLists))
  this.setState({ list: filteredLists })

 }

 removeInput() {
  console.log("removeInput    ")
  console.log(this.state.searchByGenre)
  this.setState({ searchInput: "", showDeleteButton: false, searchByGenre: false })
  document.getElementById("searchField").disabled = false;
  this.filter(this.state.searchInput)
 }

 render() {
  //alle 's komen in deze array, zodat ze gefilterd kunnen worden OBV title.
  if (this.state.list === undefined || this.state.list.length == 0 && this.state.searchInput == "") {
   //init list
   console.log("render ")
   console.log(this.state.searchByGenre)
   this.filter(this.state.searchInput)
  }

  return (
   <div class={style.list_container}>
    <input class={style.searchBar} type="text" id="searchField" placeholder={this.state.searchInput} onBlur={this.startSearch.bind(this)} ></input>

    {
     this.state.searchByGenre ?
      <h1>ja</h1>
      :
      <h1>nee</h1>
    }
    {
     this.state.showDeleteButton ?
      <button class={style.deleteButton} onClick={() => this.removeInput()}>Remove</button>
      : null
    }
    {
     this.state.list.map((item, index) => {
      return <div>
       <p>{item.title}</p>
      </div>
     })
    }
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: The above 2 functions don't work at the same time - is it means you are trying both actions simultaneously?

Comment: @SelvaTS No that's not what I mean. I meant if I comment method A out the method B works and vice versa. But I need the 2 functionalities to work once the method got triggered.They will operate individually not simultaneously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: issue with the search and filter functin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56282084/react-issue-with-the-search-and-filter-functin)

Answer (score 0):

SetState is an async operation that takes a callback function. I suspect that your second function runs before the first SetState is finished.

Also, you are modifying the DOM yourself. You need to let React do that for you just by modifying state. I don't have time to write up an example now, but hopefully this helps in the meantime.

Comment: also, input is a self closing tag

Answer (score -1):

can you modify your search func,

```
//search
startSearch(input) {
    const { value } = input.target
    const { searchInput } = this.state

    if (!this.state.searchByGenre) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            searchInput: prevState.searchInput = value,
            showDeleteButton: prevState.showDeleteButton = true,
  }))

    JSON.stringify(value) !== '' ? this.filter(value) : this.startFilter(searchInput)
    }
}
```